# Unzip a zip file in BlackBerry Java app

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, zip

I am trying to write code that unzips a zip archive and places the output in another folder.

Do I have to use a third party library? Does anyone have some code to get me started?

```
    ZipEntry dataZE;
    InputStream isData = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + dataName + ".zip");
    StringBuffer sbData = new StringBuffer();
    ZipInputStream dataZIS = new ZipInputStream(isData);
    FileConnection file =
        (FileConnection)Connector.open(
            "file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/documents/" + filename,
            Connector.READ_WRITE
        );
    if (!file.exists()) {                               
        file.mkdir();
    }                   

    while ((dataZE = dataZIS.getNextEntry()) != null) {
       out.write(dataZE );
       out.flash();
       dataZIS.closeEntry();
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [ZipME](http://zipme.sourceforge.net/) for unzip the zip archive files in Java ME / Blackberry applications.

Look on this sample code:

```
ZipEntry dataZE;
InputStream isData = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + dataName + ".zip");
StringBuffer sbData = new StringBuffer();
ZipInputStream dataZIS = new ZipInputStream(isData);
while ((dataZE = dataZIS.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    // do something...
    dataZIS.closeEntry();
}
```

Comment: How do I use that? I can't seem to be able to find a sample source code that can help me get started.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the code. How do I create a folder in order to place these files in? Can the code i wrote in my edited works?

Comment: you can place into inside of src path or add into ur lib path(using netbeans).

Comment: Hi. I am done as what you said but i am getting a nullpointerexception.

Comment: where u placed in ur zip file?

Comment: It's in a sd card. I have downloaded a zip file from server and now i am trying to unzip it and place it in another folder in my sd card. I have tried using the code you have provided but giving me a exception.

Comment: I have created a folder using fileconnection FileConnection file = (FileConnection)Connector.open(ZipFileFolder ,Connector.READ_WRITE);
     if (!file.exists()) {                 
     file.mkdir();
     }                                                              And I am trying to unzip this file and place it in the above folder.

Comment: The FileIOException is telling me that the zip file is not a file.

Comment: I think u made the mistake on file path. I think you need to do some changes on getClass().getResourceAsStream(...). And make sure the file path and try it.

Comment: I have changed the file path as InputStream isData = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + "file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/documents/job.zip"); But it is still giving me the same exception.

Comment: I dont knw ur file path is correct or not. but dont use "/" before "file:..." and make sure the file system. try to get the zip file as stream.

Comment: are u create the zip file successfully?

Comment: I am able to open the zip file using a real ZIP utility. Right now I am not getting that error anymore. However, I am wondering on how to write the zip file stream to a folder? Will it be using a outputstream?

Comment: Try like this. FileConnection fileConn = (FileConnection)Connector.open(fileName);
InputStream isData = fileConn.openInputStream();

Comment: I am wondering on how to create a new directory in order to unzip the files into.